# On video streams (RTSP specifically) does grab returns the most recent frame?

Tags: opencv

I'm using OpenCV to process a video stream that is provided via RTSP protocol. It's very easy to connect to the stream and read the frames. However, I'm having some timing issues and I want to make sure I'm doing it right.

The question is: how does `VideoCapture::grab` works in RTSP streams regarding frame buffering - does it retrieves the most recent frame provided by the stream or does it retrieves frames from a buffer? If so, can I control the buffer?

Comment: Links to documentation are greatly appreciated - I'm just having trouble find the proper information.

Comment: it will deliver frames in sequence, and not drop stuff, unless you choke it too long. then all bets are off. choking of local camera devices can result in a crash, or enormous amounts of latency. whatever video I/O backend is responsible for RTSP will eventually run out of buffer space and get mad at you. there is a property that can be set and that would adjust *some* buffer size, but don't expect that to work here! it's for video devices, not for network streams.

Comment: OpenCV is the wrong library for this. you need more control. use ffmpeg or gstreamer directly. that is not OpenCV's job. OpenCV's video I/O abilities are designed to be convenient, not arbitrarily customizable.